# Computing the eigenvalues of $A+E$ where $A$ is an upper triangular matrix whose diagonal entries are all zero and $E$ is a rank one matrix

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Let us consider the backward-shift matrix $B=(b_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ whose entries are given by $b_{k,k+1}=1$ and the other entries are all 0. We also  consider  $X=(x_{ij})\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ where
$x_{n,1}=1$ and the  other entries are all zero.

Obviously, the nilpotent matrix $B$ admits only 0 as the eigenvalue. The sum $B+X$ is the circulant matrix and  it is well-known that its spectrum are just the nth roots of $1$.

Let us consider an upper triangular matrix   $A=(a_{i,j})\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with

$$\begin{align*}
a_{i,i+1}&=1& \\
a_{i,j}&=0 ~~ &~~ j\leq i \\
a_{i,j}&\in\{0,1\} &~~ i+2\leq j
\end{align*}
$$

> Q. Are the eigenvalues of $A+X$ distinct?

Comment: If $A$ is zero and $n \ge 2$, then $A+E$ has only the eigenvalue $0$ with geometric multiplicity $n-1$ and algebraic multiplicity $n$. Am I overlooking an assumption?

Comment: Yes, we need to make some modification.

Comment: Instead of $i\le j+2$, did you mean $j\ge i+2$?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis, Yes. Thanks.